# WordPress plugin for forms with a (hand-drawn) signature field

Tags: gratis, wordpress, forms, plug-in, signature

I am looking for a free (as in “free beer”) plugin to create a basic form in WordPress. I need the following features:

- Text fields (e.g. for providing a name)
- Multiple choice (checkbox) fields
- Text areas (e.g. for a short paragraph)
- **(Hand-drawn) signature field**

On submission, the data should be either stored in a database (and accessible via the WordPress backend) or sent to a mail address.

There seem to be a lot of form plugins for WordPress out there (as an arbitrary example, see [this blog post](https://www.isitwp.com/best-wordpress-contact-form-plugins/)), and many of them also have a free version, and many of them also have a signature field, but usually not in the free version.

### What I've found out so far

- [Forminator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/forminator/) has a signature field, but only in the Pro version.
- [WPForms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpforms-lite/) has a [signature addon](https://wpforms.com/addons/signature-addon/), but that [seems to require a Pro license](https://wpforms.com/docs/how-to-install-and-use-the-signature-addon-in-wpforms/).
- [Formidable Forms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/formidable/) has a [signature field that is only available in a paid version](https://formidableforms.com/features/digital-form-signatures).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Contact Form 7**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) is a free plugin to create forms. By default, the contents entered into the form are sent via e-mail to a configurable address, however, it appears like it is also possible to add database support, if needed.

It does not have a signature field built in, however, there are at least three free addons to add one:

### ⭐ Signature Field For Contact Form 7 – CF7Sign

I've been using this addon in production for a while now and it works fine. I have the following remarks:

**It is not possible to change the size of the signature field**, which is a bit small in my opinion.

When configuring how the mail sent to you looks, you need to...

1. ...put the signature field in the "attachments" section (not the "message text" section), otherwise the mail will contain the image as base64-encoded text chunk.
2. ...or set the mail content type to HTML and use something like `<img src="[however-you-named-the-signature-field]" />` in the "message text" section.

The signature image files are temporarily saved in the `uploads/wpcf7_uploads` directory. While this sounds awfully like a security vulnerability, **a `.htaccess` file denies all requests to it** (although I was unable to find where in the code this file is created) and the files are deleted soon after the mail is sent. **I suppose this is reasonably safe.**

- [Signature Field For Contact Form 7 – CF7Sign](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-signature/)
- [Change the size and Background Color of Signature](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-the-size-and-background-color-of-signature/)

### Digital Signature For Contact Form 7

Size of signature field can be configured. However, in the free version you can only include the signature in the mail as a link to an image file uploaded to your server (not as attachment).

The signature image files are (apparently) permanently saved in the `uploads/dscf7_signatures` directory and **accessible without authentication**.

**I would not use this plugin without protecting the `uploads/dscf7_signatures` directory** (e.g. by requiring additional authentication).

- [Digital Signature For Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/digital-signature-for-contact-form-7/)
- [Free vs. Pro comparison](https://www.plugin999.com/plugin/digital-signature-for-contact-form-7/#tab-free-vs-pro)

### Contact Form 7 Signature Addon

Has not been updated in three years. As the Contact Form 7 maintainer warns against using more or less any plugin (as there could be vulnerabilities), I definitely had no interest in installing one that seems to not even be maintained any more.

- [Contact Form 7 Signature Addon](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-signature-addon/)
- [Warning against the use of vulnerable add-on plugins](https://contactform7.com/2022/08/16/warning-against-the-use-of-vulnerable-add-on-plugins/)